# Spring 4.0.5 -> 4.2.2 XML no longer valid - Endpoint no longer returning JSON

Tags: json, spring

Scenario: Using gradle to update from Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE to 4.2.2.RELEASE causes an endpoint to return XML instead of JSON.

I have an endpoint on my server that returns a list of objects. Previously, I could hit this endpoint in my browser and view the JSON object in a nice format due to my JSONView extension. After upgrading Spring, however, that same endpoint now displays XML in the browser. However, when using js to make a request to the same endpoint, I am given JSON.

Is there something I need to change to revert to the old behavior while still maintaining the 4.2.2 release?

It seems to be stemming from this issue, which Spring's reaction to changed between the two versions: https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting/issues/118.

The following is my `spring-api-servlet.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.XXX.spring" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding the following to `spring-api-servlet.xml` worked:
    

`<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
          class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>

    </bean>`

Comment: flipped my comment to an answer, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the details but this is probably a content type negotiation thing. spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc has a high level description. In spring increments, spring will sometimes fiddle with or re-order message converters, meaning the one that "wins" is non-specific if the request accept header is broad.